# Guidance on Xamarin Listview Filtering

Tags: listview, xamarin, filtering

Working on my first App with Xamarin.  I've created a Cross Platform Mobile App with Master Page.

I've got my list working on ItemsPage.xaml  I'm able to filter the list using a SearchBar above the ListView.

I would like to extend this ability.  Each item on my list has a Type, or multiple Types associated with it.  I've got this in a SQL Lite Database.

I would like to have this list of types available with Switch Controls next to each.  This would be something they can set, and it filters the list.  I'm pretty confident on coding the actual filter process, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

The comment from Jason, below, guided me to using a Modal Page.

I've got the modal page setup with:

```
    <Grid Margin="0" Padding="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="btn_CommitChanges" Text="Save Filters" Clicked="btn_CommitChanges_OnClicked" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btn_CancelChanges" Text="Cancel" Clicked="btn_CancelChanges_OnClicked" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
    <ScrollView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">>
        <ListView x:Name="CategoriesListView" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadCategoriesCommand}"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Switch IsToggled="{Binding isSelected}" Toggled="OnSwitchToggled" x:Name="{Binding CategoryType}"></Switch>
                            <Label Text="{Binding CategoryType}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

I can see the switch toggling, but I don't know how to identify which Switch is being toggled.  Ideally, I wouldn't need to know, I could gather which switch controls are enabled with by Save Filter button.

```
        public void btn_CommitChanges_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SAVE SETTINGS TO USER CONFIGURATION
        Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }

    protected void OnSwitchToggled(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Switch sw = (Switch)sender;
        //How to get which Switch Control Toggled
    }
```

In Summary, main question is how I can make an array of values associated with my Enabled switch Controls in the OnClick event, or how can I determine which switch was toggled

Comment: This isn't really a question that has a definitive answer.  I'd probably suggest putting the filter UI in a modal that pops up after a button click.

Comment: Sounds like a good suggestion.  If I wanted to put the button next to the search bar, how would I do that?  Something like [BTN] [Search Bar -----]  Also, is the modal that pops up, how does that work?  Is it another page?  If it's not quick, I'll google it, but guessing you might know and I can use that as the answer.